# Problem with Reading a txt File into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a code to read some text from the txt file which looks like this:

```
Car:
     Model: Ford
     Color: Red
     Cost: $123123.91
     Car Type: Sedan
     Towing: Included

Car:
     Model: Mitsubishi
     Color: Yellow
     Cost: $12312.00
     Car Type: Sedan
     Towing: Not Included

Car:
     Model: Honda
     Color: Grey
     Cost: $1231.00
     Car Type: Sedan
     Towing: Not Included
```

to an Arraylist. but the all the text gets stored at index position 0.

I want each order to be stored in a different index position.

The Arraylist 'orders' stores orders entered into gui which works perfectly.
These orders are written to a text file when exit is pressed

On the next run when i press load button all the orders are read from the same text file to a different ArrayList 'orders2'.

I have tried using the for loop but the problem seems to be with the way i read/store orders to the text file.

```
public void save() throws FileNotFoundException {

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, false));

    for (Object orderlist : orders) {
        pw.println(orderlist);
    }
    pw.close();
}

public void load() throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
    scan.useDelimiter("  ");
    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        orders2.add(scan.next());
    }

    System.out.println(orders2.get(0));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit")) {
        try {
            save();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(0);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scanners work by tokenizing the stream you give it as input. Tokens are things that are separated by a separator. You told it that tokens are separated by two spaces. Given that your text file doesn't contain 2 spaces anywhere inside it, the whole content, soup to nuts, is one single token.

If I read your code (which is incomplete), I see `for (Object orderlist : orders)`: This can't be right; that implies that orders is a list or array of lists of orders. You really have a list of list of orders? Neither an array nor a list would print like that, so I doubt it; that means your variable names are misleading, likely because you're not quite aware of what your own code is doing. Furthermore, Using `Object` there is likely not correct. Surely `orders` is an array or list of `Order` objects or perhaps `String` objects.

With that more clear this code would be easier to understand and comment on.